How to calculate the limit of convergence for a Taylor Series?
I recently started learning about integral and differential calculus and I was intrigued by one aspect: Taylor Series. For some series, you can approximate it for any value from the starting value, but for others you cannot. For example:
$$f(x) = \cos(x)$$
Where an equivalent Taylor series can be constructed based on the point $x$ and expanding outwards:
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \frac{x^{2n}}{(2n)!}$$
Whereas for other functions such as:
$$f(x)=\ln(x)$$
And the appropriate Taylor series around say, $x = 1$ wouldn't converge for points:
$$x<0\;\text{ or }\;x>2$$
The question is:
Is there a discrete function or formula for which to estimate the values for $x$ for which the value of the Taylor series will converge?

Does https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radius_of_convergence answer to you question?

The radius of convergence of the Taylor series about the point $a$ is the distance to the singularity of the function closest to $a$. The logarithm function has a singularity at the origin, hence the radius of convergence is the distance from the expansion point $1$ to the origin, i.e., $1$. The cosine function has no singularities in the complex plane, hence its power series converges everywhere.

One very useful sort of formula is Cauchy-Hadamard, giving the radius of convergence,  and it works for the more general setting of complex power series $\sum a_n(z-z_0)^n$ as well:
$r=\frac 1{\limsup \mid a_n\mid^{\frac 1n}}.$
As mentioned in the comments the radius is the distance from $z_0$ to the nearest singularity.
Note that for all $z$ within $\mid z-z_0\mid\lt r$ the power(Taylor)  series will converge.

Are there any more formulae of this sort?

A Taylor series is a special case of a power series.   We have the comparison test, the ratio test, the root test , and the integral test for those.   This one comes from the comparison test applied with a geometric series.   If memory serves.
